# Version issues in Restsharp reference

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, nuget, restsharp

I'm having a rather weird issue. In a solution, 2 projects implement RestSharp (dependencies of Mollie and Plivo). However both use a different nuget package. One uses the signed version, the other one the normal one. The one with the normal one works, no problems. The one using the signed one acts weird. I get the following error :

Could not load file or assembly 'RestSharp, Version=100.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=**********' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

When I go to the properties of the reference I see that it's referencing the file in the correct folder and correct version (path) but in the version of the reference it states 100.0.0.0. I can't change this, I've tried through .csproj then it just shows 0.0.0.0 as a version and doesn't find the reference at all out, in packages.config its set right..

I also tried referencing the dll in the packages directory directly, deleting it from nuget but also no luck. It shows as version 100.0.0.0 again. Is this an issue with the dll or am I the issue?

Also in object browser it shows it as 2 versions (the one installed with plivo and the one with mollie..) but there are no references anymore to the difference (Restsharp vs restsharpsigned)

[image]

Comment: did you find any soultion?

Comment: My problem was due to the fact that I was calling project 2 from project 1. Project 1 also had the RestSharp package, but a different version. When the debugging entered project 2 it noticed that it had already loaded the package, but it was the wrong version. It didn't look any further to load the package it really needed. I found out by looking at the modules window in debugging.

Answer (score 1):

The RestSharpSigned version shows as 100.0.0, because the RestSharp.dll use [Strong Name](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wd40t7ad(v=vs.110).aspx) to named it as 100.0.0. You could open it with [NuGet Package Explorer](https://npe.codeplex.com/releases/view/629447) to check the assembly information.
[image]

And I have tested installed both of Mollie and Plivo package in my project, everything works fine. So the problem should be related to your solution.

Please create a new solution without any custom code and install Plivo package in the new project. After build successful, please copy your original project files to the new project, it could help you confirm which file causes this issue.

Comment: Do you have resolved your problem? If not, please share a sample project about your issue to help us reproduce your issue.

Comment: I've this problem. I think you tried only creating a new project and install packages of mollie and plivo than build. Yes it builds well with any problem. The error which OP and me get is a runtime error.